# How to set up a Yaws yapp?

Tags: erlang, yaws

I am struggling with setting up a yapp for Yaws. Can anyone provide a link to documentation or copy paste a short example here?

Sorry that this is a rather unspecific question, but I am more or less lost :-)

Thanks,
Jan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have checked the [Yaws yapp page](http://yaws.hyber.org/yapp_intro.yaws) (be sure to "make docs" in yaws/applications/yapp directory of the checked out files) the author of [yawn](http://wiki.github.com/davide/yawn/) has posted a couple of good "make it work" wiki entries.

[Using Yapps](http://wiki.github.com/davide/yawn/1-using-yapps)

[Getting Yapps to work](http://wiki.github.com/davide/yawn/2-getting-yapps-040-to-work)

Also poke around on the [yaws mailing list](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?forum_name=erlyaws-list), there are a few regulars that jump in on yapp questions there